# What does this symbol mean for this shortkey?

Tags: macos, shortcut

Got a new Mac for work when I've traditionally worked with Windows and I'm having trouble deciphering the shortcuts. For example, I have no idea what the first two keys are in this one: [image]

The first key appears to be a `^` which is the result of pressing the `shift` and `6` key at the same time. However, that doesn't work for the shortcut to open the terminal which is a combo of ^`

I also have no earthly idea what the second key is in that shortcut. Can someone provide some clarity?

Comment: See the Apple guide ["What are those symbols shown in menus on Mac?"](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-are-those-symbols-shown-in-menus-cpmh0011/mac). Also, they have a massive list of ["Mac keyboard shortcuts"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) (which'll have a lot you don't care about, but if you're trying to find something specific it's a handy list). BTW, one standard thing Windows people get wrong on macOS is that closing a window doesn't always quit the app. To quit an app, use Command(⌘)-Q (or choose application menu > Quit).

Answer (score 1):

The first is the contol key and the second the option key